# Как пишется "не()вечно"? Слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография

Будет ли верным писать "невечно", если в предложении нет противопоставлений, отрицательных местоимений и наречий, слов: ничуть, нисколько, вовсе, далеко, отнюдь и отрицаний?

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, если это краткое прилагательное со значением "преходящий, тленный, недолговечный, бренный". Например, у В. Горелика в "Осаде Кушки":

> И вообще, правительство так же невечно, как и принимаемые им решения.
>   https://www.proza.ru/2018/05/28/720

Или: Невечно  всё.

Но: Жизнь длится не вечно (а мало). Довольно трудно придумать пример с наречием невечно в неотрицательном значении (тленно,бренно). Я думаю, если это наречие не вечно, то оно уже содержит в своём значении отрицание, поэтому пишется раздельно.